# Backend files being load as public - Angularjs / Node / Gulp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, fuse

I have been struggling to know why my back end files are being loaded as front end files.

As I am working a new project with angular+node+gulp, it seems a bit confusing for me.

Here goes an image with the exceptions..
Any suggestion?

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Ngo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to answer your question in a current form.

If JavaScript is loaded on the frontend, it must be because it is referenced in the `<script>` tag in your HTML. Maybe you are concatenating and minifying more than you need - not only frontend but also your backend files, and they end up being bundled together.

Comment: I found out that gulp inject (gulp/inject.js) had this line that was turning my back end directories into public ones:

**path.join(conf.paths.src, '/api/**/*.js')**

Tnks.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have your frontend and backend JS files in the same directory set for gulp to fetch from? So they all get concatenated and loaded from the web page?